# Remove .php extension using htacess and also keep other rules or rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force remove .php extension but also I want to keep other rules that are already working for website like **category.php** and **article.php** that are being used to rewrite URLS, I tried my best to do so but sometimes it gives me Server Error and sometimes I got 500 Internal Server error.
Please review my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+?)/page/(.+)/?$ category.php?url=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+?)/?$ category.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+?)/?$ article.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC, L]
```

The last and the second line of code making trouble for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: still getting 500 Internal server error for category.php rewrite

Comment: Restart apache and check files and folders permissions.